# Could pushing changes made in pipeline to origin cause problems?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently I have a release pipeline which is run when we're ready to publish a package to a private `NPM` registry. This pipeline takes a few parameters (like the version) which is used to do the following within the pipeline:

- Update the version in the `package.json` file (using `npm version`)
- Update the version in the `package-lock.json` file (using `npm version`)
- Update the `CHANGELOG.md`
- Add an annotated `git` tag

These changes are then committed and pushed to origin with the following `PowerShell` snippet:

```
git switch -c $(Build.SourceBranchName)

# Stage all the changed files (only showing the staging of one file for brevity).
git add package.json

# The variable 'version' was supplied to the pipeline via a parameter.
git commit -m "chore(release): v$(version) [skip ci]"

# Push the changes to remote.
git push -u origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)

# Create the tag and push it to origin.
git tag "v$(version)" -a -m "chore(release): v$(version) [skip ci]"
git push origin "v$(version)"
```

#### My Concern

My understanding of the [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) task is that it checks out the commit that our `main` branch is currently pointed to at the time of running the pipeline, putting us in a detached head state (hence why I used `git switch` above).

Now imagine another developer created a `PR` which was approved and merged with `main` just prior to the final stage of my release pipeline (which is where I'm executing the `PowerShell` above).

In this case I could potentially run in to a `merge` conflict or (and probably more likely) the `push` to `origin` in the pipeline will be merged with whatever changes were merged from the `PR`. That would mean that new `commit` wouldn't actually point to the `object` graph that corresponds to what was released.

I guess in my case I could do one of the following:

1. Create a `release/v**` branch and push the changes there (making tagging useless)
2. Make sure no `PR`'s are accepted when running the release pipeline

With the first option (creating a release `branch`) I'm unsure how I'd make that work with change log updates.

I'm curious what other options I have in this case? I'm also wondering if I'm *making a mountain out of a molehill*..

What do some of you other folks do when updating the version of you packages and auto appending a change log?

Note that the use of `NPM` is immaterial to the question.

Comment: You shouldn't be pushing build outputs into version control. You can publish packages to an Azure Artifacts feed for consumption by others; you don't need to push it into version control.

Comment: Not talking about build artifacts here. I'm not pushing the compiled (to JavaScript) to origin. I'm talking about making changes to the version number in the `package.json` file and the change log. After these changes are made in the pipeline a build is triggered. Those build artifacts are stored in the pipeline artifacts and later pushed to the NPM registry (not version control). But, I want to `push` those version and change log changes to origin as well as a tag.

Comment: If I didn't push to origin how do I maintain continuity with the change log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could pushing changes made in pipeline to origin cause problems?

Not in the way you're thinking.

> Now imagine another developer created a PR which was approved and merged with `main` just prior to the final stage of my release pipeline... In this case I could potentially run in to a merge conflict or (and probably more likely) the push to `origin` in the pipeline will be merged with whatever changes were merged from the PR.

That's not possible. Your `push` will simply fail because the tip of your local `main` branch will have diverged with its remote counterpart (`origin/main`). When this happens, either you must force push to blow away the remote changes (which you obviously don't want to do on a shared branch such as `main`), or you must merge in the remote changes and then attempt the push again. The latter is probably what you should do in this scenario.

So the actual problem you have is sometimes your pipeline is going to fail. There are a few potential solutions that come to mind:

1. You can minimize the likelihood of failure by pulling `main` right before pushing. (Make sure you use the default `merge` instead of `rebase` in this case. If you move your new commit on top of the latest `origin/main` you'll be lying about what you actually built. Consider using `git pull --no-rebase` here in case a config is altered to prefer rebasing when pulling.) Note it's still possible that during the short amount of time (perhaps a few seconds) between pull and push, that someone else still completes *another* PR into `main`, but the chances of this are generally pretty low. If you have so much activity that even this isn't enough you could put it into a loop with, say, 5 or 10 tries, that on a push error it retries. One slick thing you can do in this case, is in the loop, reset hard back to the new commit your build generated before re-attempting the pull (merge) again. This way even if it takes 5 tries you'll only have 1 new merge commit instead of 5 in a row.
2. Some repos will create and tag the new commit detached off of `main`. Then you just push it on its own and you don't have to push `main` at all. The advantage of this is it can't fail, and you don't pollute `main` with lots of build commits. The downside though is when viewing the history of `main`, you can't also see all of the builds, which makes it slightly harder to answer the question of "What's the first build that contains this change on `main`?" (And in your case, this may not work at all since your script updates a changelog file which I assume would require history of each build.)
3. Avoid making new commits altogether and just tagging the commit on `main` that was built. This usually involves some sort of build number injection into the process so that you don't need to actually capture the build number changes in code, and the tag on `main` will suffice for knowing what was in that build. (Again, this may not work if you need the changelog history as part of the build.)

#1 is the probably the lowest hanging fruit in your situation where you can just add a single `pull` call to your script before the step "# Push the changes to remote".

**Side Note:** I see you're using `git push -u` which suggests at that point your `main` may not be tracking `origin/main`. If you decide to go the `pull` route, and you don't have tracking yet, you could either setup the tracking earlier in the script, or you can replace `pull` with a `fetch` and `merge`, perhaps like this:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/main
# Push the changes to remote.
git push -u origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

Comment: Note sure why I didn't offer this in the Side Note, but also, `git pull origin main --no-rebase` should work as well.